# 404 error when posting to Web API 2 action using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

OK, there is lots going on here so I will try and keep my question and examples as simple as I can. With that in mind, please ask if you need any additional information or clarification on anything.

**The code**

I have a Web API 2 project which has a number of controllers and actions. The particular action I am having problems with is defined in the **ContactController** as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public MyModel GetSomething(System.Nullable<System.Guid> uid)
{
    return GetMyModel(uid);
}
```

In case it matters, my routing is setup as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now I have another project that is required to call the above action. For calling the Web API I am using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx). Note that I have lots of other actions calls which are working correctly, so this isn't a connectivity issue.

The code I am using to call the Web API method is as follows:

```
using (HttpClient client = GetClient())
{
    var obj = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("uid", someGuid.ToString()) };
    var response = client.PostAsync(path, new FormUrlEncodedContent(obj)).Result;

    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
}
```

In this instance, `path` is basically:

> localhost:12345/api/contact/getsomething

**The problem**

The `PostAsync` call `Result` (i.e. `response` in the above code) gives this message:

> {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Pragma: no-cache
>     X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcUHJvamVjdHNcTGltYVxMaW1hIHYzXERFVlxMaW1hRGF0YVNlcnZpY2VcYXBpXHVzZXJhY2Nlc3NcZ2V0bW9kdWxlc2FjY2Vzcw==?=
>     Cache-Control: no-cache
>     Date: Fri, 18 May 2018 10:25:49 GMT
>     Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>     X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>     X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>     Content-Length: 222
>     Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>     Expires: -1
>   }}

If I put a breakpoint inside the aciton then it doesn't fire. However, what I find strange is that when I call it, Visual Studio (2018) tells me that the specific action has a "failed request" on that specific action. So clearly it must know which method I am trying to call?

At this point I am running out of ideas on how to debug further. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unrelated but don't block on async with `.Result`. You'll probably deadlock after you figure out your 404 issue.

Comment: @Crowcoder: I will investigate, but I don't actually want it to be Async

Comment: Then use a synchronous API like `HttpWebRequest` or some other.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can use the same endpoint as for getting and posting.

so you probably need:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(System.Nullable<System.Guid> uid)
{
    return GetMyModel(uid); //make sure you got it, oterhwise return a NotFound()
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(InputModel model)
{
    _service.doMagicStuff();
    return Ok();
}
```

cheers!

Comment: btw; do inject your HttpClient instead of doing a 'using', httpclient should be a singleton, cheers! (take a look at .net core 2.1 (httpclientfactory)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will look at that. But regards to answer, I would like to use post method for my requirement.

Comment: what do you mean? It is in place right? (changed the method name): `Post`

Comment: I mean I want to keep my controller action the same as is in my question (unless I have a good reason to change it). So I want a POST action called GetMyModel that takes Guid value.

Comment: is the guid parsing going wrong? what happens if you try it as a string?

Comment: oww, and add: [Route("{uid}")]

Comment: Possibly, I am not sure how to work out if it's a parsing issue. I will try your suggestions

Comment: so start with using a string and add the attribute: [Route("{uid}")] the `uid` has to match the paramname of your function

Answer (score 0):

not sure but error may be because of you are passing keyvalue pair

```
var obj = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("uid", someGuid.ToString()) };
var response = client.PostAsync(path, new FormUrlEncodedContent(obj)).Result;
```

instead of guild only i.e. only string value expected by function , so it will be

```
var response = client.PostAsync(path, new FormUrlEncodedContent(someGuid.ToString())).Result;
```

method should be

```
[HttpPost]
public MyModel GetSomething(string uid)
{
    return GetMyModel(Guid.Parse( uid));
}
```

Comment: hmmm... I can give it a go. But then what if I want 2 parameters `(Guid uid, string somethingElse)` how will it work it out?

Comment: @musefan - then you need to cretae class and pass value , thats what I am doing when i am calling api from my angular code , i pass class object which have all properties , like in your case you should have class with two property

Comment: Yeah, I have thought about using a model... but I wanted that to be a last resort as I don't want a custom class for every single action if I can help it

Comment: @musefan - its good to have model specially for case of post and when your method parameter increses more then 2

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the guid with the FormUrlEncodedContent but the requests content type is application/json.
I recommend you to send it as a json like this

```
using (HttpClient client = GetClient())
{
    var obj = new { uid = someGuid.ToString()) };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = client.PostAsync(path, content).Result;

    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
}
```

Then in the api controller, use the FromBody attribute to declare that the parameter is read from the request body

```
[HttpPost]
public MyModel GetSomething([FromBody]RequestModel model)
{
    return GetMyModel(model.uid);
}

public class RequestModel
{
    public System.Nullable<System.Guid> uid { get; set; }
}
```

Also, if you only have one Post method in the contact controller the url `localhost:12345/api/contact` will be enough

Comment: Do I have to change the parameter to `RequestModel` class? I really want to get it to work with just the `Guid`. Also, I am getting the same problem when I try you suggestion...

Comment: @musefan if you want the body to be key - value based then you need to wrapp the parameters in a model. Did you also change the path/url to only be POST localhost:12345/api/contact